How to send MDM commands to push an app to iOS device in python
"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                            <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
                            <plist version="1.0">
                            <dict>
                                <key>Command</key>
                                <dict>
                                    <key>Identifier</key>
                                    <string>com.zhiliaoapp.musically</string>
                                    <key>RequestType</key>
                                    <string>RemoveApplication</string>
                                </dict>
                            </dict>
                            </plist>"""

In this plist, I provide the command to remove a third-party application installation.
I used to perform this task using Python 2.7, but I now want to update the code to Python 3. How can I send a command to an iOS device using Python and Django? This is a plist form of commands.
